# Unable to update drupal core because the project is open in phpstorm

Tags: drupal, composer-php, drupal-8

I'm running Drupal VM and trying to update Drupal core.
I just run `composer update drupal/core` it seems to run fine, my entire core folder is removed and a new cache file is created by composer.
But then composer somehow fails to remove the cache file and stops?

I'm running my console as admin on Windows 10.
Doing the composer update from within the Drupal VM (vagrant ssh)

I've updated Drupal core like this before and had no issues. Not sure what's wrong?

```
vagrant@drupalvm:/var/www/drupalvm/eura/webroot$ composer update drupal/core
    1/4:        http://packagist.org/p/provider-latest$bd26fae873ac4aadd03c03c5d1737acf6a0c347b376fe4f6aac30df09c2dbc83.json
    2/4:        http://packagist.org/p/provider-2017-01$023baddfc70d3f47f448977fe79fa793625d88bb7b862f6ea36f02c9a31eda1c.json
    3/4:        http://packagist.org/p/provider-2017-04$3b999da86ab9b70dd889a3c4c4d7baecb55506bfeba762f376b385c42f776d5d.json
    4/4:        http://packagist.org/p/provider-2017-07$5cf29e45d29a0f45b6c9fdc8b447c48f6d4f4312273ab60a07ab838dbf9bcf5b.json
    Finished: success: 4, skipped: 0, failure: 0, total: 4
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 0 installs, 1 update, 0 removals
  - Updating drupal/core (8.3.6 => 8.3.7): Loading from cache    Update failed (Could not delete core/5effb5112dfc3bc54201da4e351268c0: )
    Would you like to try reinstalling the package instead [yes]? y
  - Removing drupal/core (8.3.6)


  [RuntimeException]
  Could not delete core/5effb5112dfc3bc54201da4e351268c0:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like I had the project open in PHPStorm which caused this.

Or it fixed itself some other way ;)